# From exponential to squareless monomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-variables, exponential-function, tropical-geometry

Currently, I am going through [Geometry of the Restricted Boltzmann Machine](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4425) by Cueto et al.

In section 2, the authors defines $\psi (v, h)$ as follows.

$$
\psi (v, h) = e^{(h^\top W v + b^\top v + c^\top h)}
$$

Here, $v$ is the state of the visible layers, $h$ is the state of the hidden layer, and $W$ is the connectivity matrix of a restricted Boltzmann machine.

Then the authors convert this exponential function into a squarefree monomial. To do that they defines the following functions.

$$
\gamma_i = e^{c_i}\\
w_{ij} = e^{W_{ij}}\\
\beta_j = e^{b_j}
$$

They the monomial is:

$$
\psi (v, h) = \Pi^k_{i = 1} \gamma^{h_i}_i \cdot \Pi^k_{i=1} \Pi^n_{j=1} w^{h_i v_j}_{ij} \cdot \Pi^n_{j=1} \beta^{v_j}_j
$$

I don't understand how to get to the monomial from the exponential function. This is how I tried.

$$
\psi (v, h) = e^{(h^\top W v + b^\top v + c^\top h)}\\
= e^{h^\top W v}  e^{b^\top v}  e^{c^\top h}\\
= e^{h^\top W v}  e^{(b^\top)^v}  e^{(c^\top)^h}
$$

What do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a matter of exponent manipulations.
Start with:

$$
\begin{align}
e^{b^T v} &= e^{\sum_{j=1}^n b_j v_j} \\
          &= e^{b_1 v_1} \cdot \dots \cdot e^{b_n v_n} \\ 
          &= (e^{b_1})^{v_1} \cdot \dots \cdot (e^{b_n})^{v_n} \\
          &= \prod_{j=1}^n \beta_j^{v_j}
\end{align}
$$

The derivation for the other terms is similar.